# Updating the render form a function in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm ignorant towards how Reacts render works and i was wondering , how or if it possible to update a style element from a variable created in a function. See the following :

this is my function that's called in order to determine the amount of columns for the sytle elemnt "gridTemplateColumns".

```
 function getSize() {
        var number 10
        var ColumnNo= "";
        for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            ColumnNo+= "auto ";

        }

    }'
```

And this is the Grid Container with the style inside:

```
<div className="grid-container" style={{ "gridTemplateColumns": styletest }}>
```

I know that it works when you load the page , but how do you update the render with this new variable ?

Comment: consider using state https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the variable in the state of your component and update it with setState or pass it to the component using props and update the value from the parent component.

This way every time the variable changes, the render function will be called